# dirPagination does not work (Angular JS pagination)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, dirpagination

I am trying to use [dirPagination](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination) but it does not work. See my code in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/18BxNhHRNyRoI17sBGQF?p=preview

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0-beta.5" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="bootstrap@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('PsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.data = [
            {a:1, b:1},
            {a:2, b:2},
            {a:3, b:3}
        ];
    }]);
</script>


<script src="dirPagination.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="PsCtrl">
    ItemCount: {{data.length}}
    <ul>
        <li dir-paginate="item in data | itemsPerPage: 2">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
    <dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I only get this as output:

```
ItemCount: 3
  ⋅
```

But I would expect pagination controls at the bottom and this output as a first page:

```
ItemCount: 3
⋅ {"a":1,"b":1}
⋅ {"a":2,"b":2}
```

When I use `<li ng-repeat="item in data">{{ item }}</li>` it shows the correct list.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you need to run your plnkr is to include dirPaginate into your angular module:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination'])
```

And change path to pagination HTML template in dirpagination.js:155 to

```
templateUrl:  'dirPagination.tpl.html',
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Download [dirPagination.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/master/src/directives/pagination/dirPagination.js) from here.
2. Now include *dirPagination.js* to your page.
3. Add *angularUtils.directives.dirPagination* in your module like this

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
```

4. We use `dir-paginate` directive for pagination ,add `dir-paginate` in `tr` tag

```html
<tr dir-paginate="event in events|orderBy:['id', 't']:true | itemsPerPage: 5">
```

5. Add below given code anywhere on your page or where ever you want.

```html
<dir-pagination-controls
                max-size="5"
                direction-links="true"
                boundary-links="true" >
</dir-pagination-controls>
```